# How to switch VS Project from 32bit to 64bit?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, build, 32bit-64bit

I am having trouble moving my WPF project from 32 bit to 64 bit. I recently realized I need my program to be able to use more than 2gb of memory.

What I did was I changed my project's platform target from Any CPU (with preferred 32 bit checked) to x64.

I then got an error stating “XXX” does not exist in the namespace “XXX" and realized it was probably because I did not change the CPU target for my other libraries.

Then when I launched the program in my developer machine, it works perfectly fine using both visual studio and Click Once installing after deploying. However, when I test the deployed executable using a few different 64 bit machine, the program starts behaving erratically with some functions not working properly.

I have no idea how to debug since it works perfectly fine in my developer machine but not on any other computer? Am I not changing the target platform correctly?

Comment: Do you have any 32-bit dependencies (dlls) in the project? What about Windows API calls?

Answer (score 1):

The assembly ITSELF built by youself when targeting "Any CPU", but you should check out every third-party assemblies that used in your project if they are targeting "x86". If you change the target of your own project to "x64", make sure all of the dependencies are for "Any CPU" or "x64".